# How to apply model free deep reinforcement learning when the access to the real environment is hard?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Deep Reinforcement Learning can be very useful in applying it to real-world problems which have highly dynamic nature. Few examples can be listed as is finance, healthcare etc. But when it comes to these kinds of problems it is hard to have a simulated environment. So what are the possible things to do?

Comment: Sorry, it is hard the access to the real environment or to have a simulated environment?

Comment: yeah. When you think beyond, applying RL to games how can we have our own simulators?  For an example let's say we need to apply RL to forecast activity in model-free behavior. So we need some sort of environment to learns from.

Comment: You need some sort of environment or maybe only the data acquired from the environment in form of tuples <state, action, next state>. It's better to have access to the environment in order to be able to apply any kind of action, but some times this is not possible. In such case, if you have a large quantity of data, probably you'll be able to find an improved policy. Should I elaborate an answer? Is your question in this direction?

Comment: Hey! exactly this is what I wanted. I think you should answer here. Also mentioned more about instances where we cannot access the environment or it's hard to simulate unlike in Atari, cart pole etc. More real-world problems.  Let's take a problem I want to forecast human activities with first-person vision with RL. So I created a reward function and I do not know state transition function. Also, I have so many states where I cannot go for tabular methods. So I need to use deep Q learning(model-free). Think my environment is a kitchen. States are visual feed near sink, cooker  etc.

Comment: Actions are moving between those states. How can I simulate this. Because here human is moving between states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first comment a couple concepts trying to give you future research directions according to your comments:

- Probably the term "forecast" is not suitable to describe the kind of problems solved by Reinforcement Learning. In some sense, RL needs to do an internal forecast process to choose the best actions in the long term. But the problem solved is an agent choosing actions in an environment. So, if your problem is a forecast problem, maybe other techniques are more suitable than RL.
- Between tabular methods and deep Q-learning there exist many other methods that maybe are more suitable to your problem. They are probably less powerful but easy to use (more stable, less parameter tuning, etc.) You can combine Q-learning with other function approximators (simpler than a deep neural network). In general, the best choice is the simplest one able to solve the problem.
- I don't know how to simulate the problem of human activities with first-person vision. In fact, I don't fully understand the problem setup.

And regarding to the original question of applying RL without accessing a simulated environment, as I previously said in the comments, if you have *enough* data, you could probably apply an RL algorithm. I'm assuming that you can store data from your environment but you can not easily interact with it. This is typical, for example, in medical domains where there exist many data about [patient status, treatment, next patient status], but you can not interact with patients by applying random treatments. In this situation, there are some facts to take into account:

- RL methods generally consume a very large quantity of data. This is specially true when combined with deep nets. How much data it is necessary depends totally of the problem, but be ready to store millions of tuples [state, action, next state] if your environment is complex.
- The stored tuples should be collected with a policy which contains some exploratory actions. RL algorithm will try to find the best possible actions among the ones contained in the data. If the agent can interact with the environment, it should choose exploratory actions to find the best one. Similarly, if the agent cannot interact and instead the data is  gathered in advance, this data also should contain exploratory actions. The papers [Neural Fitted Q Iteration - First Experiences
  with a Data Efficient Neural Reinforcement
  Learning Method](http://ml.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/former/_media/publications/rieecml05.pdf) and [Tree-Based Batch Mode Reinforcement Learning](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume6/ernst05a/ernst05a.pdf) could be helpful to understand these concepts.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) 

" I'm assuming that you can store data from your environment but you cannot easily interact with it" This is IT. The perfect answer I ever had on this issue. :)

Comment: Exactly, that is the situation I was trying to describe. Very welcome, it's a pleasure to be helpful!

Comment: @ Pablo EM - Can you check this paper - http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kkitani/pdf/BK-ACCV16.pdf

Comment: This paper uses RL to forcase long term activities with first person vision.  Their RL agents can predict the moving trajectory (giving left ,right) or the action to take.  In their way , they say this is how they simulate the enviroments to apply Q learning - 

"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50001520/how-to-apply-model-free-deep-reinforcement-learning-when-the-access-to-the-real"

Comment: I think now you can get a clear idea. Can you explain me how in above case they created their simulated environment

Comment: Hi @ShamaneSiriwardhana, probably you can get a much higher quality response to such specific question if you write directly to the paper's author. Usually authors are very happy to receive feedback and questions from people interested his work. For me, to read carefully the paper it would require a couple of hours or more, and currently I don't have enough time (and I don't want to give you a response without being sure about what I'm responding).